# How to stop SQL Injection in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Python to talk to Google's new Cloud SQL (mySQL) database. I have a working example, but I was wondering if the example code is ok to stop SQL Injection attacks?

```
mdata = self.request.get('mdata')
conn = rdbms.connect(instance=_INSTANCE_NAME, database='metarsql')
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Note that the only format string supported is %s
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO metar (metar_data) VALUES (%s)', (MySQLdb.escape_string(mdata)))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Is there a function or command to add to stop SQL Injections? Maybe a function to stop multiple SQL commands?

There wasn't much on Google Search for Cloud SQL and Injections.

Best regards

Andre F Bruton

Answer (score 2):

A very good guide : [Prevent sql injection in python using cursor.execute correctly](http://love-python.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/prevent-sql-injection-in-python-using.html)

It does not matter if it's Google's server or anyone else.

Comment: How would you add more than 1 %s variable from the above example?